# Unexpected results in voltage to current converter (simulation is Ok)

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, mosfet, current, converter

The circuit below shows a **Voltage to Current converter** based on a **DAC**, **opamp**, **transistor** and **switches**. The last one, allow to have a bipolar signal output.

[image]

During the experimentation, the DAC is setup to get ~330mV in the resistor (330 ohm) at the transistor source in order to get **1mA current** and the LOAD.

The circuit (except the DAC) is **simulate** (in multisim) with **success**.

The switches used during experimentation are based on **MAX4623**.

[image]

In the **real world**, there is an **unexpected situation** when the switch turn on (please, refer to the waveform below).

[image]

The waveforms of the LOAD (2.2K ohm) are shows in the scope chart (PIN+ and PIN-). Everything is as expected, except the **part marked in red color**.

The **expected waveforms** are show below. These waveform allow to have a **bipolar current** (+/-) in the load.

[image]

Any suggestion in order to understand the unexpected situation is appreciated. As well as an approach to avoided.

**Edit:**

As suggested by Tony, the voltage in the mosfet source has been reduced to ~110mV.

[image]

The results in this experiment change a little a show the waveforms below:

[image]

**Edit:**

As suggested by Spehro, a switch could be added to avoid the op-amp to saturate.

[image]

Below the proposal and expected signals.

[image]

**Edit:**

Below a proposal using a current mirror, following Tony and Spehro suggestions.

[image]

The waveform results improved with this proposal:

[image]

However, there are some **not desired situations**:

- The left part of the mirror is always on, increasing the power consumption. Perhaps, a new question (based on this experimentation) will be: **how to implement a ultra low power voltage-current converter (0 to 10mA)**?
- The **initial peak** (when the switch turn ON) is too high for the load. Please, refer to waveform below.

[image]

**Edit (explain of unexpected situation):**

As suggested, the **unexpected situation** is explained by the **setting time of the op-amp**. In summary, once the transistor turn on, the op-amp need time for adjustment (with the feedback). To solve this situation, the transistor is keep ON in order to allow the op-amp not saturated. One solution is presented in the proposal (see previous edit), where an additional transistor is added (making a mirror).

Thanks

Comment: You haven't shown your switch circuit.

Comment: The switches used during experimentation are based on MAX4623

Comment: Why are you trying to accomplish a differential PWM current source? It has too many mismatched impedances.

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish a biphasic signal with fixed current (as show in the question)

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly unusual and suggests your high side analog switches are high impedance. Check that they have adequate gate voltage.   Try CD4066's or similar for your experiment.

Reality is complex since the schematic does not show all the stray capacitance and protection diodes and unexpected results occur.

[image]

The switches complement the polarity of current to the load but then go to Tristate (unknown charge voltage)  This does not seem practical and is neither a Sample and hold, nor a switch capacitor design, but something that does not behave properly with high impedance charges.

Comment: Tony, thanks for your comments.

Comment: During the experimentation, the switches were based on MAX4623. The gate voltage level are compatible with the Logic Supply-Voltage Input (~3V).
From your previous message, a new experiment was performed to reduce the voltage in the feedback around 100mV. In this case, the unexpected situation is still present, but a little different. Please, refer to the images in the post which I updated with latest experiment.

Comment: This experiment has too many problems with complex high impedance, probe capacitance. Explain why you are doing it.

Comment: If you could measure switch voltage using two probes A-B, you may find more reasons why it fails.

Comment: Tony, please, may you list the problems that you consider with the circuit or experiment? 

The goal is to generate a **biphasic signal in a variable resistive load** (1k to 10k ohm) with a fixed current (0.1 to 3mA). 
The main constraint is to reduce the power consumption as much as possible. 

The biphasic signal is defined as below:
  ![biphasic signal](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Gabriella_Tognola/publication/3091253/figure/fig2/AS:669169527832586@1536553856503/Shape-and-characteristic-parameters-of-the-biphasic-current-pulses-delivered-at-the.png).

Comment: Tony, the answer to the question in the waveform chart "What you should expect?" is already answered in the post question with another waveform chart

Comment: Tony, considering the comment about the switch going to Tristate, it's not true. Please, take into account that the two (2) switched are enabled at the same time (i.e. during φ1 or during φ2). Which means, there is not tritstate during those two periods. My post question is related with the those two periods only.

Comment: Yes OK. But the faulty signals should be the opposite polarity to the good one  when either  φ1 or φ2 is ON and **not the same polarity**, so your implementation error is not apparent on the schematic.  It started OK then went wrong with  φ3 added.  Your error is hidden to us. Poke your fingers around the original circuit with stray finger capacitance to Vdd or Vss until you find the node with the problem on the LOW Side switch

Comment: Is the Gnd missing for Vss on the switch IC? bad connection?  Overall the question is poorly documented for part & pin numbers, spec sheet links and photo layout. Needs improvement. Then use Test Point numbers  TP# in future or proper labels

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks again for your comments and suggestions. 1) the polarity seems OK according with the schematic. For example, when φ1 is ON, the PIN+ must have 18V and PIN- must have "18V minus voltage in LOAD". 2) As explained in the post, the addition of φ3 is a suggestion from Spehro, which I presented in the post for clarification only. This test is not performed because will consume more power than the latest proposal with the current mirror. 3) The connections were verified multiples times.

Comment: In summary, the unexpected situation is already explained by the setting time of the op-amp (as mentioned previously by Spehro). Additionally, a solution is proposed at the end for other readers. I don't have further questions.

Comment: Polarity OK ?? Then why does the same waveform appear on both PIN+ and PIN-. It should be complementary or differential.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for your comments. The polarity and voltage are correct. As you suggested previously, the voltage in the resistor to ground (i.e. 110 Ohm) was adjusted from 330mV to 110mV. This means a current of 1mA. In others words, there is a voltage drop in the resistor of 2.2K (the same placed in the switches) that cause a difference waveform between the PIN+ and PIN- during the stages φ1 and φ2. In summary, the waveforms in the post are correct, showing a different between the each PIN of around 2.2V at the stages φ1 or φ2.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your timebase is 500us/div, consider that the settling time is listed at 660us typical and the slew rate as 10V/ms.

You may do better if you short the current source to +V during the 'off' periods so the op-amp does not saturate.

Comment: Hi Spehro, thanks for your feedback. 
As you mentioned, the unexpected situation seems related with the settling time of the DAC internal op-amps, which saturate when the mosfet is disconnected. 
In this case, I agree the solution proposed will improve the situation. I updated the images with this proposal.

Comment: My concern with such proposal is the power consumption. I'm looking to reduce the power consumption as much as possible. In thi case, there will be a constant current from V+ to GND. The DAC is set one time (in order to reduce power) and the CPU controlling it, get to sleep. There is a custom circuit taking care of the switches signals.
In other hand, another proposal could be keep the op-amp on and use a mirror as shown in the diagram (please, refer to the post edited).